# Write file in a new directory based on user input

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, mkdir

There are lots of suggestions on how to create a directory, but I did not come across elegant solutions to saving a file in a newly created directory. The code saves files in the main folder, not id specific. I'd greatly appreciate your help. Thanks!

I'm using Windows 10 Python 3.

1) check whether "TrainData/xx-xxx" directory exists

2) if it does not exist:

- create a subfolder within the "TrainData" directory and name it based on unique input (id) - this now works
- save the file within this new directory (TrainData/xx-xxx) and name it xx-xxx....jpg

3) if it exists:

- save the file within this new directory (TrainData/xx-xxx) and name it xx-xxx....jpg

  ```
  id = input('Client ID:xx-xxx')     

  directory = "TrainData/" +str(id)
  if not os.path.exists(directory):
      os.makedirs(directory)

  #with open(os.path.join(directory, '.' +str(id))) #I can't get this to work

  file_name_path = directory + str(id)+ '.' +str(count)+ '.' +str(timegm(datetime.utcnow().utctimetuple())) + '.jpg' 

  if cv2.Laplacian(face, cv2.CV_64F).var() >200:
      cv2.imwrite(file_name_path, face)

  else:
      count -= 1
  cv2.imshow('Client', frame)
  ```

}

Comment: The fundamental problem is probably not understanding the concept of a current working directory. When Python (or any command really) starts up, it remembers which directory you were in when that happened. You can `chdir` inside your code, but usually you just stay where you are, and manipulate files relative to the current directory. So for example `TrainData/foo/bar/baz.txt` refers to the file `baz.txt` in the directory `bar` which is a subdirectory of `foo` which is a subdirectory of `TrainData` which is a subdirectory of the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Its for creating a directory if not exists :

```
import os

directory = "TrainData/" +str(id)
if not os.path.exists(directory):
       os.makedirs(directory)
```

Then you can open and create a file in that directory .

```
with open(os.path.join(directory, '.' +str(count)+ '.' +str(timegm(datetime.utcnow().utctimetuple())) + '.jpg' ), "w") as ip_file:
      ...
```

Comment: Creating a directory works well, thank you.  However, I haven't been able to get the file written in it as of yet.  

        directory = "TrainData/" +str(id)
        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            os.makedirs(directory)
        
        file_name_path = directory + str(id)+ '.' +str(count)+ '.' +str(timegm(datetime.utcnow().utctimetuple())) + '.jpg' 

        if cv2.Laplacian(face, cv2.CV_64F).var() >200:
            cv2.imwrite(file_name_path, face)
                        
        else:
            count -= 1
         
        cv2.imshow('Client', frame)

Comment: you want to create an empty file ?

Answer (score 0):

All that was missing was a '+/'.  Thanks everyone!

```
id = input('Client ID:xx-xxx') 

    directory = "TrainData/" +str(id) +'/'
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
       os.makedirs(directory)

    file_name_path = directory +"ID." +str(id)+ '.' +str(count)+ '.' +str(timegm(datetime.utcnow().utctimetuple())) + '.jpg'

    if cv2.Laplacian(face, cv2.CV_64F).var() >200:
        cv2.imwrite(file_name_path, face)

    else:
        count -= 1

    cv2.imshow('Client', frame)
```